# Unable to pass the text value from result.getContents() into the myRef DatabaseReference for deleting the corresponding key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my second question and thanks in advance.

The problem is basically not being able to pass the value of qrCode(EditText) field into the myRef DatabaseReference such that the value is passed in the form of (eg.) "1-Breakfast" , "2-Breakfast" and so on...

image for database:

[image]

I have tried passing the value as return String.valueOf(qrCodes) by creating a method but it makes it keeps crashing. Our app keeps crashing.. MOreover the value keeps passing in as null.

```java
package com.vidmun.dhananjay.qrscanner;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   private Button buttonScan;
   private Button delete;
   private EditText qrCode;
   private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

   private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       myRef.addChildEventListener(new MyChildEventListener());


       delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
       buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
       qrCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);

       qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);

       buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);


       delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               deleteValueFromDb();

           }
       });
   }

   //Getting the scan results
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (result != null) {
           //if qrcode has nothing in it
           if (result.getContents() == null) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               //if qr contains data
               try {
                   //converting the data to json
                   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   //if control comes here that means the encoded format not matches
                   //in this case you can display whatever data is available on the qrcode
                   qrCode.setText(result.getContents());
                   Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       } else {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       //initiating the qr code scan
       qrScan.initiateScan();
   }

   DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(String.valueOf(qrCode));


   public void deleteValueFromDb(){

       myRef.child("0").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                   dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Can Eat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Already Eaten", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
               throw databaseError.toException();
           }
       });
   }
}
class MyChildEventListener implements ChildEventListener {
   @Override
   public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       Log.i(TAG, "childAdded " + dataSnapshot.toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       Log.i(TAG, "childChanged " + dataSnapshot.toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       Log.i(TAG, "childRemoved " + dataSnapshot.toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       Log.i(TAG, "childMoved " + dataSnapshot.toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       Log.i(TAG, "childMoved " + databaseError.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to get the value of a text field as a string:

```
private EditText qrCode
```

Calling `String.valueOf(qrCode)` will simply convert the `EditText` itself to a string, not its value.

To get the value from an edit text:

```
qrCode.getText().toString()
```

So for example:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(qrCode.getText().toString())
```